# How to check these sequences generated by i.i.d random variables are martingales?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value, sum, martingale

Let $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables.

$P(Y_i=1)=P(Y_i=-1)=\frac12$

Set $S_0=0$ and $S_n=Y_1+...+Y_n$ if $n\geq 1$

I want to check if the following sequences are martingales.
   $$M_n^{(1)}=\frac{e^{\theta S_n}}{(\cosh{\theta})^n}$$

$$M_n^{(2)}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n sign(S_{k-1})Y_k, n\geq 1,M_0^{(2)}=0$$

$$M_n^{(3)}=S_n^2 -n$$

I have no idea how to answer these questions. I think to answer these questions, knowledge of moment generating functions and its  natural logarithm   **Cumulant** is necessary.

If any member knows the correct answers to these questions may reply with correct answers.

Comment: The very first thing to consider when given such simple random variables is to apply the definition.

Comment: what does superscripts **(1),(2),(3)** of $M_n$ indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $M_n^{(1)}$ we must first check that the process is integrable. Note that $\theta\mapsto |e^\theta+e^{-\theta}|$ is an even function which is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and increasing on $(0,\infty)$ and hence attains its minimum $2$ at $\theta=0$. Now,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|M_n^{(1)}|] &= \mathbb E\left[\left|\frac{2e^{\theta S_n}}{(e^\theta+e^{-\theta})^n} \right|\right]\\ &\leqslant \sup_{\theta\in\mathbb R}\frac2{|e^\theta+e^{-\theta}|^n} \mathbb E[e^{\theta S_n}]\\
&\leqslant 2^{-n} e^{n|\theta|}\\
&<\infty.
\end{align}
As for the martingale property, for each positive integer $n$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[M_{n+1}^{(1)}] &= \mathbb E\left[\frac{2e^{\theta S_{n+1}}}{e^\theta + e^{-\theta}}\mid\mathcal F_n \right]\\ &= \frac 2{e^\theta+e^{-\theta}} \mathbb E[e^{\theta S_n}e^{\theta Y_{n+1}}\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&=\frac{2e^{\theta S_n}}{e^\theta + e^{-\theta}}\mathbb E[e^{\theta Y_{n+1}}]\\
&=\frac{2e^{\theta S_n}}{e^\theta + e^{-\theta}}\\
&= M_n^{(1)}.
\end{align}

For $M_n^{(2)}$ integrability follows readily from the bound
$$
\mathbb E[|M_n^{(2)}] = \mathbb E\left[\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{sgn}(S_{k-1})Y_k \right|\right] \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n 1\cdot1 = n.
$$
As for the martingale property,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[M_{n+1}^{(2)}\mid\mathcal F_n] &= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\mathrm{Sgn}(S_{k-1}Y_k\mid\mathcal F_n \right]\\
&=\mathbb E[\mathrm{Sgn}(S_n)Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n] + \mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\mathrm{Sgn}(S_{k-1})Y_k\mid\mathcal F_n \right]\\
&= \mathrm{Sgn}(S_n)\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}] +\mathbb E[M_n^{(2)}\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&= 0 + M_n^{(2)}\\
&= M_n^{(2)}.
\end{align}

For $M_n^{(3)}$, integrability follows from
$$
\mathbb E[|M_n^{(3)}|] = \mathbb E[|S_n^2-n|] \leqslant \mathbb E[S_n^2] + n = 2n<\infty.
$$
As for the martingale condition,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[M_{n+1}^{(3)}\mid\mathcal F_n] &= \mathbb E[S_{n+1}^2-(n+1)\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&=\mathbb E[(S_n+Y_{n+1})^2 \mid\mathcal F_n] - (n+1)\\
&= \mathbb E[S_n^2 + 2S_nY_{n+1} + Y_{n+1}^2\mid\mathcal F_n] - (n+1)\\
&= S_n^2 + 2S_n\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}] + \mathbb E[Y_{n+1}^2] -(n+1)\\
&= S_n^2 -n\\
&= M_n^{(3)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$M_n^{(1)}$ is a martingale. It satisfies the conditional expectation:

$E\left(M_{n+1}^{(1)} | S_n \right)= M_n^{(1)}$